# How can you find and list all video files and thumbnails in php?

Tags: php, html

I have a linux server filled with mp4/m4v videos (400+ and growing) and would like to create a listing of all the videos. Somewhat similar to HBO Go.

An example of what I'm trying to accomplish is scanning the current directory and listing all the video mp4/m4v files with a direct link embedded into an image.

Example of the files:

```
Dir1
   CurrentDirectoryLister.php
   Halloween (2018).mv4
   Halloween (2018).png
   Pacific Rim.mp4
   Pacific Rim.png
Dir2
   CurrentDirectoryLister.php
   NewMovie Here.mp4
   NewMovie Here.png
```

So, the user will click a link to Dir1 and which will open CurrentDirectoryLister.php and be provided with the images "Pacific Rim.png" and "Halloween (2018).png". When they click an image it takes them to the movie page "Dir1/Pacific Rim.mp4/"

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [scandir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#refsect1-function.scandir-examples) method?

Comment: If I understand the page correctly, I'd end up with an array where "[0] = Halloween (2018).mp4" and "[1] = Halloween (2018).png" when using the above example right?

Comment: [0] should be "CurrentDirectoryLister.php" and both the "Pacific Rim..." files would be in there

Comment: I think this has gotten me on the right track. I could use scandir to create my array then start with a loop that runs though x times (where x is the total files -1 then /2). Inside the loop it would echo html for the photo (starting with [2]), linking to the video (starting with [1]), then adding 2 to either number for the next loop. In theory, this should work with bulk items correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this I set up two separate arrays.

One containing only photos and one only videos.

All of my files have matching names so `$movies[1]` and `$images[1]` (Pacific Rim.mp4 && Pacific Rim.png).

Further explained by another user [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55783813/10970723)

```
<?php
$movies = glob('./*.{mp4,m4v}', GLOB_BRACE);
$images = glob('./*.{jpeg,jpg,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
$subtitles = glob('./*.{srt}', GLOB_BRACE); #To be used later.

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $lookup[pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_FILENAME)] = $image;
}

foreach ($movies as $movie) {
    $image = $lookup[pathinfo($movie, PATHINFO_FILENAME)] ?? 'default.jpg';
    echo '<a href="' . $movie . '">
            <img src="' . $image . '" style="width:300px;height:350px;border:0;">
        </a>';
}
?>
```