# Check for similar text in arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, data-synchronization

I have this code which displays logos with a link to a video file. I frequently upload files and I want to keep thinks in order. At the moment it just attaches them in order of name. So for example if I upload a movie and haven't gotten around to uploading a photo with the exact same name then from that point on any photos will be displayed with mismatching links.

What I'd like to do is display a temporary photo if the name doesn't match.

I know you can do something like if(array[1] === array2[1]) but the file extensions would be different so that would return false every time.

Code:

```
<?php
$images = glob('./*.{jpeg,jpg,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
$movies = glob('./*.{mp4,m4v}', GLOB_BRACE);
$movieLink = 0;

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<a href="' .$movies[$movieLink].'">
            <img src="'.$image.'" style="width:300px;height:350px;border:0;">
        </a>';
    $movieLink++;
}

?>
```

Example of server directory (400+ movies and >30 photos):

Dir1

- Movie1.mp4 ↰__ correct pair
- Movie1.png  ↲
- Movie2.m4v ↰__ correct pair
- Movie2.png  ↲
- Movie3.mp4 ↰__ incorrect pair
- Movie4.mp4 ↲
- Movie4.png ←-- no image to pair with

When this runs it displays 3 photos side by side which when clicked the first 2 (Movie1.png && Movie2.png) you are taken to the correct movies for each. However, when you click "Movie 4.png" you are taken to "Movie3.mp4".

Comment: You can cut off the extension (using `array_map` with custom function to cut last `.`) and use `array_diff`

Comment: I would have thought you would have a database table with this information in rather than just guessing.

Comment: Can't you post the two arrays as samples and what you expect out from the code? A bit hard to understand what exactly you want/need

Comment: I'll update the post now with an example.

Comment: Not sure the example made it any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME)` to construct a lookup array for easy verification.  The lookup array uses "extensionless" movie filenames as keys which are paired with the image filename (with its extension).

You should be looping the `$movies` array, if your project logic states that there will always be more movies than images.

```
$movies = glob('./*.{mp4,m4v}', GLOB_BRACE);
$images = glob('./*.{jpeg,jpg,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $lookup[pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_FILENAME)] = $image;
}

foreach ($movies as $movie) {
    $image = $lookup[pathinfo($movie, PATHINFO_FILENAME)] ?? 'default.jpg';
    echo '<a href="' . $movie . '">
            <img src="' . $image . '" style="width:300px;height:350px;border:0;">
        </a>';
}
```

The above snippet is not tested, but it should be pretty close.  In case you are unfamiliar, the `??` is the null coalescing operator.  It basically says assign the lookup value unless it is missing, in which case use the default value.

Here's a demo of the lookup array construction: https://3v4l.org/HJhVR

Comment: It seems to work in a small folder. I'll start testing it with my other directories. Thank you! Also, there is an extra ")" on line 2.